# Groovy's Duck Interface?

Tags: grails, groovy, duck-typing

I am assigned to develop a library that aids to a Grails app. The Grails app has tons of domain objects (about 100+ tables). I don't want my library to depend on the Grails app , which makes my library db-dependent and hard to test (Grails takes a long time to start) .

For example , the Grails app has one `Payment` domain object , which contains a lot of fields , and depends on a lot of other domain objects.

I only want some fields , not all fields or other dependent domain objects.

I'm new to groovy , knowing there's Duck Type in groovy . I thought it should be OK to define a **Duck Interface**, which I don't need to modify the Grails `Payment` object.

So , I defined :

```
interface IPayment {
  String getReceiver()
  String getContactPhone()
  String getContactEmail()
  String getUserIp()
  ...
}
```

And define a method that accepts this `IPayment` interface.

But when I pass the `Payment` object to the method, compiler complains Payment not implements IPayment...

Yes, I can force `Payment implements IPayment` , but this is not what I want.

I hope the grails app just import my library , passing the `Payment` object to my method and works.

Is there any other design techniques ?

Thanks.

---

updated : groovy 1.8.8 , sorry , no Traits.

Comment: What does your library need to do with the domain classes of your app?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa : for example : wrap this Payment object to notify external system.

Comment: But if the library wraps payment that would make it dependent on the app. Right?

Comment: That's right . But in dev time , I don't want my library dependent on the grails app. It makes development cumbersome , hard to test...

Comment: Ah, I see. However you can keep the library eternally independent of the app by adding a middle adapting layer using the adapter design pattern. This layer would live in the app but it would be rather small. That way your library would remain testable and reusable.

Comment: Yes ! That's what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is how you can create your library independently from your Grails app, and to keep it that way by using an adapter to mesh the app to the library. The adapter tricks the library into thinking that it's using the expected `Payment` interface.

## The library

Here's an example of the library.

```
interface Payment {
    String getReceiver()
    String getContactPhone()
    String getContactEmail()
    String getUserIp()
}

class PaymentProcessor {
    def process(Payment payment) {
        payment.with {
            println receiver
            println contactPhone
            println contactEmail
            println userIp
        }
    }
}
```

There's the `Payment` interface and a class which uses it.

## The app

The example app has it's own payment class, and it's a little different than the one expected by the library.

```
class AppPayment {
    String receiver
    Contact contact
    String userIpAddress
}

class Contact {
    String phone
    String email
}
```

The receiver property is identical, but the contact info is in a different class and the ip address property is named differently.

## The adapter

To make it possible to use `AppPayment` instances with the library, you can create an app-specific adapter.

```
trait PaymentAdapter implements Payment {
    String getContactPhone() { contact.phone }    
    String getContactEmail() { contact.email }    
    String getUserIp() { userIpAddress }
}
```

Usually an adapter is implemented as a class. But using a Groovy trait instead has some advantages. The first of which is that you don't need to implement getReceiver(); the equivalent property already in `AppPayment` will be used. You only need to implement whatever is different from the `Payment` interface.

## Using the adapter

There are a number of ways to use the adapter. The most explicit form is coercion.

### Coercion

```
def processor = new PaymentProcessor()
def payment = new AppPayment(
    receiver: 'John',
    contact: new Contact(phone: '1234567890', email: 'john@doe.com') ,
    userIpAddress: '192.168.1.101')

processor.process payment as PaymentAdapter
```

In this case the `AppPayment` is coerced into a `PaymentAdapter` by applying the trait at runtime. Since `PaymentAdapter` implements Payment, `PaymentProcessor.process()` accepts it.

### Groovy Category

You can handle the coercion in a Groovy Category to avoid having to use the as keyword directly.

```
class PaymentAdapterCategory {
    static Object process(PaymentProcessor processor, AppPayment payment) {
        processor.process payment as PaymentAdapter
    }
}

use(PaymentAdapterCategory) {
    processor.process payment
}
```

With the category you can avoid having to coerce with the adapter explicitly; as long as you call `PaymentProcessor.process()` within the `Object.use(category, closure)` Closure.

### Compile-time trait

Since the adapter is a trait, and you have access to the source code of the app, you can modify the `AppPayment` class to implement the `PaymentAdapter` trait. This would allow you to use an `AppPayment` instance directly with `PaymentProcessor.process()`. DISCLAIMER: This is my favorite option; I just think it's quite... Groovy.

```
class AppPayment implements PaymentAdapter {
    String receiver
    Contact contact
    String userIpAddress
}

def payment = new AppPayment(...)

processor.process payment
```

I hope this helps :)

## Warning

Although this is not an issue in most cases, I want to let you know that the runtime coercion process changes the class of the instance. For example: `println ((payment as PaymentAdapter).class.name)` prints out `AppPayment10_groovyProxy` This is not a problem unless you do something like this:

```
def payment = new AppPayment(
    receiver: 'John',
    contact: new Contact(phone: '1234567890', email: 'john@doe.com') ,
    userIpAddress: '192.168.1.101') as PaymentAdapter

// I'm going to barf!!!
something.iExpectAnInstanceOfAppPayment(payment)
```

This does not happen with compile-time traits.

## Without traits

Groovy versions prior to 2.3 do not support traits, so the adapter must be a class. You can start by creating a generic adapter in the library.

```
/*
 * Uses duck typing to delegate Payment method
 * calls to a delegate
 */
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
abstract class AbstractPaymentAdapter implements Payment {
    def delegate // Using @Delegate did not work out :(

    String getReceiver() { delegate.receiver }    
    String getContactPhone() { delegate.contactPhone }
    String getContactEmail() { delegate.contactEmail }
    String getUserIp() { delegate.userIp }

}
```

The `AbstractPaymentAdapter` implements `Payment` and expects the delegate to do so as well, but via duck typing. This means subclasses only have to implement whatever differs from the `Payment` interface. This makes implementing an adapter as a class *nearly* as concise as an adapter implemented as a trait.

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class PaymentAdapter extends AbstractPaymentAdapter {
    String getContactPhone() { delegate.contact.phone }
    String getContactEmail() { delegate.contact.email }
    String getUserIp() { delegate.userIpAddress }    
}
```

### Using the adapter

Using the adapter is simple: `processor.process new PaymentAdapter(payment)`

You can use a Groovy Category as shown earlier, but not coercion. However, it's possible to fake the coercion and achieve the same syntax by implementing `asType()` in the `AppPayment` class.

```
class AppPayment {
    String receiver
    Contact contact
    String userIpAddress

    def asType(Class type) {
        type == Payment ? new PaymentAdapter(this) : super.asType(type)
    }    
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
processor.process payment as Payment
```

Comment: Thanks . Trait is beautiful . But my groovy is 1.8.8 , which doesn't support trait :( (sorry I didn't mention this in my question)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you. I updated the question with an additional class-based adapter.

Comment: Thanks. Groovy's transform is such a magic ...  As to the `def asType(Class type)` , I cannot touch the `AppPayment` code . Anyway , it's a beautiful solution.

Comment: There's a way you can still add `asType() `to AppPayment without changing the code: The ExpandoMetaClass. It would overwrite any existing `asType()`, but you can do something like this: `AppPayment.metaClass.asType << {Class type -> type == Payment ? new PaymentAdapter(delegate) : throw new Exception("Type $type not supported") }` You can do this in Bootstrap.groovy.

Comment: Thanks . I wonder if any way to `automatically` override this `asType` ? So that the grails app just need to import my lib , doesn't need to *prepare* the `asType` ? If there's no such `asType` prepared , groovy complains `GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Payment@180510a0' with class 'Payment' to class 'IPayment'`

Comment: That makes sense. The Object.asType() implementation doesn't know how to create an IPayment. You won't be able to automatically override asType, not for technical reasons (there is a way to do it, I just don't remember how) but because asType needs an adapter, and adapters are app-specific; not reusable.

Comment: I found a way to handle the payment adaptations automatically. We've gone beyond the initial question (which I don't mind), so just get with me on Google+ https://plus.google.com/109886199751744223967/posts

Comment: Hi , I cannot find it in your Google+'s wall ... ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `as` operator to coerce your `Payment` to `IPayment`.

```
interface IPayment {
  String getReceiver()
  String getUserIp()
}


class Payment {
    String receiver
    String userIp
}


def account(IPayment payment) {
    "account: ${payment.receiver}, ${payment.userIp}"
}

def payment = new Payment(
        receiver: 'my receiver',
        userIp: '127.0.0.1')


assert account(payment as IPayment) == 'account: my receiver, 127.0.0.1'
```

Pure duck typing is dynamic and doesn't care about types:

```
def duckAccount(payment) {
    "duck account: ${payment.receiver}, ${payment.userIp}" 
}


assert duckAccount(payment) == "duck account: my receiver, 127.0.0.1"
```

Note the object resulting from the `as` operator have no enforced protocol, and can fail at runtime if the coerced type doesn't implement the right methods:

```
interface IPayment {
  String getReceiver()
  String getUserIp()
  String getPhone()
}


class Payment {
    String receiver
    String userIp
}


def account(IPayment payment) {
    "account: $payment.receiver, $payment.userIp, $payment.phone"
}

def payment = new Payment(
    receiver: 'my receiver', 
    userIp: '127.0.1.1'
)

try {
    assert account(payment as IPayment) == 
        "account: my receiver, 127.0.1.1, null"
    assert false
}
catch (e) {
    assert e.toString().contains(
        "MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Payment.getPhone()")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer.